# Mongoose find returns empty array (works fine for other collections)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, find, capitalization, empty-list

I have been writing a restful api in nodejs fairly succesfully for the most part.  There are two collections in the MongoDB that I am accessing that return empty strings and happen to be the only collections that contain capital letters in their names.  When I use MongoClient, I am able to access these collections just fine, so I know that it is not an out of date mongodb driver.

one example is when I try to access a collection called bulkBuds

```
//bulkBuds model

var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var BulkBudsSchema = new Schema({
  sourceLicense: String,
  quantity: Number,
  strainName: String,
  priceProfile: String
});

mongoose.model('bulkBuds', BulkBudsSchema);
```

The controller has a bit of excess logic in the query, but a simple find returns an empty string as well.

```
//bulkBuds controller
var express = require('express'),
  router = express.Router(),
  mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  BulkBuds = mongoose.model('bulkBuds'),
  Friends = mongoose.model('Api'),
  config = require('../../config/config'),
  jwt = require('express-jwt');

    module.exports = function (app) {
      app.use('/api/bulkBuds/', router);
    };

    router.get('/:license', jwt({secret: config.secret}), function (req, res, next) {
      if(!req.user.friend){
        res.status(401);
      }
      Friends.findById(req.user.id, function(err, friend){
        if(err) throw err;
        if(!friend) res.send("friend does not exist");
        if(req.user.username != friend.username) res.send("invalid user");
        console.log(req.params.license);
        console.log(BulkBuds.find({}));
        BulkBuds.find({'storeLicense': req.params.license, 'availableForSale': true},
        "sourceLicense quantity strainName priceProfile", function (err, bulkBuds) {
          if (err) return next(err);
          console.log(bulkBuds);
          res.send(bulkBuds);
        });
      })
    });
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Very difficult to answer without being able to test against your database.  But I would try a few things.

1. refactor {'storeLicense': req.params.license, 'availableForSale': true} to create the object outside of the query, and then console log that object prior to passing it to the query.  That will ensure everything is as you expect.
2. Remove "sourceLicense quantity strainName priceProfile" as the second argument to BulkBuds.find, and replace with an empty object.  I usually pass an object as the second param with the following syntax {_id:1,quantity:0} to modify the projection.  Your syntax may work, but just in case I would try running the query without to see if that yields any results.
3. Confirm quantity in your db is indeed a Number and not a String.  I know mongoose won't let you insert records that don't validate, not sure about querying.  Most likely not the issue, but doesn't hurt to verify.
4. After creating the Bulkbirds schema try this:

mongoose.model('bulkBuds', BulkBudsSchema, 'bulkBuds');

Another long shot, but perhaps it has something to do with mongoose pluralizing the collection names. Using the above syntax will ensure it's querying the bulkBuds collection.

Once again, difficult to pinpoint without being able to test, but hopefully those ideas help.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Thats great advice, unfortunately I had taken those steps already but I definitely appreciate your help.

Comment: hmmm,  I added number 4, not sure if that will help but worth a shot.  Documentation can be found here.  http://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html

Comment: Strangely a console.log statement fixed it.  It may be a synchronicity issue.

Comment: mongoose.model('bulkBuds', BulkBudsSchema, 'bulkBuds'); save the day